# Assumptions for derivative of an integral

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

for example if: $$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$$
and I want to use the fact that: $$F'(x) = f(x)$$
Do I simply need to show that f(t) satisfies the assumptions that it is continuous and bounded above and below, 
are there any other assumptions I missed?

Comment: You only need continuity. No boundeness assumptions are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is an intervall in $ \mathbb R$, if $f:I \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and if $a \in I$, then

$$F(x) := \int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt \quad (x \in I)$$

is differentiable and $F'=f$ on $I$. That $f$ is bounded on $I$ is not needed.

Example: $I=(0,1]$ and $f(x)=1/x.$

Comment: I believe your example needs $a>0$ as well as $x$ in $(0,1]$

Comment: @Peter a belongs to I, as does x, so it's already accounted for.

Comment: @Green05 Yes. Missed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to show that $f(t)$ is continuous (then, on any closed bounded interval, it will automatically be bounded above and below). See http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma121/FTCproof.pdf.

Comment: So boundedness is necessary, it is just that by proving continuity on a closed interval implies boundedness?

Comment: Boundedness is not necessary as such. The function $f$ just needs to be integrable. The point I made is that if you restrict to $f$ being continuous, then saying that it also needs to be bounded is redundant.